# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS but not for subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have a site that contains subdomains, I have installed a SSL certificate, and I want HTTP requests to be redirected to HTTPS, however I don't want subdomains to be redirected to HTTPS except a couple: *app.example.com* and *api.example.com* which have to be HTTPS.

I have setup the code below, however it doesn't handle subdomains, my subdomains are currently redirecting to the HTTPS version of the root domain.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.io
    ServerAlias *.example.io
    Redirect permanent / https://example.io/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
...
```

How shall I do this?

**Edit: To be a bit more specific.**
How can I...?

- Redirect all http://example.com to https://example.com
- Avoid redirections for http://sub1.example.com, http://sub2.example.com, http://sub3.ex... and so
- Redirect http://app.example.com and http://api.example.com to https://...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can pretty easily be done with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^(((app|api)\.)?example\.com)$"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R,L]
```

The first condition ensures the rule is only triggered for non-HTTPS requests. This can be omitted if you put the rule in your port 80 vhost and only accept non-HTTPS requests on that port.

The second condition inspects the HOST header to ensure it's example.com, app.example.com, or api.example.com.

The rule itself issues a redirect to the HTTPS counterpart. %1 is a backreference to the full HOST header contents (%0 could work here as well and allow you to omit some parens) and $1 is a backreference to the path (minus the leading forward slash).

NOTE: You can probably use the [if directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) as well to limit the redirect as desired.

Comment: That was it, spot on.